# Why does the change of the Lyapunov function with time of a particular orbit necessarily have a minimum value in Chataev's instability theorem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-dynamics

In the proof of [Chataev's instability theorem](https://math.la.asu.edu/~kawski/classes/mat475/handouts/chetaev.pdf), it is assumed that there exists an $m>0$ such that m is the minimum value of the change in the Lyapunov function $V$ with time for the given positive orbit. Why is this the case? Is it not possible to have an orbit where $V^\prime$ decreases monotonically with the limit $0$?

Comment: Note that $\dot V$ is strictly positive on a compact set and so the minimum is positive.

Comment: @JohnB But why should the minimum exist in the first place?

Comment: You have a continuous function on a compact set.

Comment: @JohnB Ah that clears it up. Thanks!